# Allocate small struct to 32 bit aligned in 64 bit system

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-alignment

**The problem:** I'm implementing a non-blocking data structure, where threads alter a shared pointer using a CAS operation. As pointers can be recycled, we have the ABA issue. To avoid this, I want to attach a version to each pointer. This is called a *versioned pointer*. A CAS128 is considered more expensive than a CAS64, so I'm trying to avoid going above 64 bits.

I'm trying to implement a versioned pointer. In a 32b system, the versioned pointer is a 64b struct, where the top 32 bits are the pointer and the bottom 32 is its version. This allows me to use CAS64 to atomically alter the pointer.

I'm having issues with a 64b system. In this case, I still want to use CAS64 instead of CAS128, so I'm trying to allocate a pointer aligned to 4GB (i.e., 32 zeros). I can then use masks to infer the pointer and version.

The solutions I've tried using `alligned_malloc`, padding, and `std::align`, but these involve allocating very large amounts of memory, e.g., `alligned_malloc(1LL << 32, (1LL << 32)* sizeof(void*))` allocates 4GB of memory. Another solution is using a memory mapped file, but this involves synchronization that we're trying to avoid.

Is there a way to allocate 8B of memory aligned to 4GB that I'm missing?

Comment: There's not going to be a C++ standard compliant solution (`std::max_align_t` is never 4 GB), so you need to specify the OS and compiler to have a prayer of getting a non-portable answer for your particular use case. To me, this sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040), and it's likely there is a better solution if you detail *why* you're doing this (e.g. it's possible you could get away with *relative* pointers that are only 32 bits in size even on 64 bit systems, or CAS128 might not hurt performance as much as you think even if you need 64 bit pointers).

Comment: Just to be clear, `std::max_align_t` isn't a restriction on maximum possible alignment you can request, but it's what most "easy alignment" solutions are built around, and the few that provide overaligned memory like `aligned_alloc` are not optimized for this case, as you've seen.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes I don't think it's a typo. OP wants a 64 bit pointer where 32 bits are granted to be 0 (and can be used for something else). That's why the required alignment to 4 GB...

Comment: 4 GB alignment is a quite heavy demand IMHO. There must another solution. (I mean 4 GB alignment to save 32 bits somewhere...)

Comment: @ShadowRanger The problem (X) is CAS operations having contention on a pointer, only we have the ABA issue (a pointer can be recycled). To avoid ABA, we use a version number. Using a CAS128 is considered using a DCAS which is more expensive that CAS, so we're trying to stick to 64 bits.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Could you explain your relative pointer thought? I'm unfamiliar with this term.

Comment: @BlueGranny Why do you consider a 64-bit DCAS to be acceptable on a 32-bit architecture and a 128-bit DCAS unacceptable on a 64-bit architecture?

Comment: @EOF Excellent question! It's due to cache line sizes in 32 bit systems. A minimal cache line is 64 bit, so the CAS is optimized for those sizes even in 32 bit systems. See : CMPXCHG - https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg

Comment: @BlueGranny: It's basically reimplementing segmented memory (what old 16 bit systems in the '80s used to be able to address non-trivial amount of memory where they could have 32 bits of RAM, but only 16 bit registers to address it); instead of the "pointer" being a pointer on its own, it's effectively an index into a known memory segment. So you confine these "pointers" to point to a single 4 GB chunk of memory (allocated up front and never changed, unless you want even more complexity), and the "pointer" is really just an index into that 4 GB chunk.

Comment: @BlueGranny: You can read more [about how the old Intel 8086/80286/80386 used to do this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation), using a combination of segment registers (which still exist even today, but are largely unused since 32 bit became the norm) and an offset from the base address the segment register used. Hardware won't support this for you anymore, but it's trivial to implement yourself in terms of array access.

Comment: @BlueGranny If *that* is your concern I'm sure you've taken the necessary measure of aligning your 64-bit DCASes on 32-bit systems to 64-bit boundaries, right? If not, 128-bit DCAS is no worse.

Comment: @EOF You raise an interesting point. Thanks! I'll go back and double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, a non-portable solution that limits the code complexity creep to the point of allocation (see below for another approach that makes point of use more complicated, but should be portable); it only works on POSIX systems (not Windows), but you could reduce your overhead to the size of a page (not 8 bytes, but in the context of a 64 bit system, wasting 4088 bytes isn't *too* bad if you're not doing it too often; obviously, the nature of your problem means that you can't possibly waste more than `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE) - 8` bytes per 4 GB, so that's not *too* bad) by the following mechanism:

1. `mmap` 4 GB of memory anonymously (not file-backed; pass `fd` of `-1` and include the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag)
2. Compute the address of the 4 GB aligned pointer within that block
3. `munmap` the memory preceding that address, and the memory beginning `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)` bytes after that address

This works because memory mappings aren't monolithic; they can be unmapped piecemeal, individual pages can be remapped without error, etc.

Note that if you're short on swap space, the brief request for 4 GB might cause problems (e.g. on a Linux system with heuristic overcommit disabled, it might fail to allocate the memory if it can't back it with swap, even though you never use most of it). You can experiment with passing `MAP_NORESERVE` to the original request, then performing the unmapping, then remapping that single page with `MAP_FIXED` (without `MAP_NORESERVE`) to ensure the allocation can be used without triggering a `SIGSEGV` at time of writing.

---

If you can't use POSIX `mmap`, should it really be impossible to use CAS128, you may want to consider a [segmented memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation) like [the old x86 scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) for these pointers. You block allocate 4 GB segments (they don't need any special alignment) up front, and have your "pointers" be 32 bit *offsets* from the base address of the segment; you can't use the whole 64 bit address space (unless you allow for multiple selectors, possibly by repurposing part of the version number field for example; you can probably make do with a few million versions rather than four billion after all), but if you don't need to do so, this lets you have a base address that never changes after allocation (so no atomics needed), with offsets that fit within your desired 32 bit field. So instead of getting your data via:

```
data = *mystruct.pointer;
```

you have a segment pointer like this initialized early:

```
char *const base_address = new char[1ULL << 32];  // Or use smart pointer of your choosing
```

wrap it in a suballocator to partition the space, and now lookup is instead:

```
data = *reinterpret_cast<REAL_TYPE_HERE*>(&base_address[mystruct.pointer]);
```

I'm sure there are nifty ways to wrap this up better with custom allocators, custom `operator new`s, what have you, but I've never had to do this in C++ (I've done similar magic in C, where there are no facilities to make it "pretty"), and I'd probably get it wrong, so I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this as answered because I think your solution should work. Many thanks!